# Global function not defined in Angular controller code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a global function declared as follows (only necessary bits):

```
initiateCheckList = {};

$(function() {

    initiateCheckList = function() {
    ...
    }
```

And then I have a function inside an Angular controller that tries to call that function, but I get the error `initiateCheckList is not defined` when the following function is called:

```
$scope.updateSuburbs = function () {
    $scope.suburbs.getModel($scope.areas.areaId);
    initiateCheckList();
};
```

This function is nested inside a controller, and is bound to a dropdown `change` event like so:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="areas.areaId" ng-change="updateSuburbs()">
```

What is Angular doing so that I can't call a global function, and how can I fix things so I can call it?

Comment: Is error that it isn't defined or isn't a function? Create a demo that replicates problem.

Comment: there shouldn't be a problem calling that function from the controller, can you share more of your code or maybe create a plnkr ? see this test plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EksybmUDDe7Ht2QLysgm?p=preview

Comment: @NitsanBaleli Your plunker makes it clear that there is nothing framework based stopping my code working, so I must have a home-made bug somewhere. I'll keep looking until I find it and hopefully answer the question for other users. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the ideal way of defining global properties/function in angular:

You've got basically 2 options for "global" variables:

```
use a $rootScope [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope][1]
use a service [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services][1]
```

$rootScope is a parent of all scopes so values exposed there will be visible in all templates and controllers. Using the $rootScope is very easy as you can simply inject it into any controller and change values in this scope. It might be convenient but has all the problems of global variables.

Services are singletons that you can inject to any controller and expose their values in a controller's scope. Services, being singletons are still 'global' but you've got far better control over where those are used and exposed.

Using services is a bit more complex, but not that much, here is an example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('UserService', function() {
  return {
      name : 'anonymous',
      printData: function() {console.log('Print Data');}
  };
});
```

and then in a controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.name = UserService.name;

    UserService.printData();
}
```

I hope it would help you to understand adding global properties/functions in angular.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP situation of trying to use a function from outside angular